# Is there any difference between "on doing something" and "after doing something"?

Tags: prepositions

Is there any difference between *on doing something* and *after doing something*? For example:

> **On finishing** my homework, I watched a movie.
>
> **After finishing** my homework, I watched a movie.

If there isn't any difference, as I suspect, then which one is more common?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In most contexts, ***on*** [doing something] and ***after*** [doing it] are equivalent and interchangeable. But there can be a nuance of difference, in that strictly speaking the ***on*** version implies ***when, at the actual time of*** [doing it], whereas ***after*** obviously implies a (usually only very *slightly*) ***later*** time.

It's tricky to find an example context that's likely to clearly distinguish between the two, but consider...

> 1: ***On*** taking off his shirt he found there was a button missing
>    2: ***After*** taking off his shirt he found there was a button missing

Perhaps it's just me, but I find #1 far more natural, since the fact of the missing button would become apparent ***during*** the shirt removal process, not ***after*** it.

---

Okay - here's another one...

> 3: ***On*** entering a new hotel I always tip the doorman
>    4: ***After*** entering a new hotel I always tip the doorman

...where again the first version makes more sense to me, since I picture typical hotel doormen as standing ***outside*** the front entrance. I'd like to picture myself as a wealthy patron casually slipping the doorman a substantial tip ***as he doffs his cap / tugs his forelock*** and holds the door open for me to go through, thereby ensuring that I'll get attentive service from him for the duration of my stay.

---

EDIT: I should point out that the preposition ***on*** in my examples #1 & #3, and "equivalent" alternatives such as ***when, while, during,...*** are syntactically *optional*, and *don't affect meaning*.

By default, the relationship between the primary clause *(**I tip the doorman**)* and the participial clause *(**entering a hotel**)* is one of *simultaneity*. But other "time-based" prepositions *(**before, after, since,...**)* indicate different temporal relationships, which DO affect meaning.

Comment: Hmm... It's almost a puzzle-worthy question, finding a case where the difference stands out. On entering a crowded street I always worry about pickpockets.  After entering a crowded street I always worry about pickpockets.

Comment: @puppetsock: I'm ***so*** glad to see that comment! I knew exactly what "potential difference" I wanted to flag up, but I was quite taken aback when I realised I was really struggling to come up with a meaningful "minimal pair" to give as an example. When I thought of a slightly better one shortly after posting the first section, and came back to edit it in, I half-expected to find a slew of comments suggesting other examples - with the implication that I must be a bit slow-witted if my first example was the best I could come up with. It's weird how hard this one is though!

Comment: You said that "on" means during the process of something. Then what is the difference between "on taking off his shirt he found there was a button missing" and " taking off his shirt he found there was a button missing"? I am really confused. Could you clear that up?

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope: Mea culpa. I've added an extra section to cover that issue.