# the meaning of "slip a tip"

Tags: meaning

An [ELL post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/239564/109190) says

> I'd like to picture myself as a wealthy patron casually **slipping** the doorman a substantial **tip** as he doffs his cap / tugs his forelock and holds the door open for me to go through, thereby ensuring that I'll get attentive service from him for the duration of my stay.

which uses a pattern of "slip a tip".

I am aware that "tipping" means the customer gives $1 per bag to the doorman. I don't understand the meaning of "slip a tip". Could someone please give a hint?

Comment: The reason I wrote ***casually slipping*** rather than plain ***giving*** was specifically because I wanted to "downplay" the significance of that action. In the context of my answer there, I wanted to underline the fact that the "primary" activity going on at the time was ***me entering the hotel***, which I felt was relevant to the syntactic point I was making. But I forgot that on a *learners* site I should be more careful about how I use idiomatic expressions that might not be so easily understood. Would ***handing*** or ***passing*** have been better than ***slipping*** for you there?

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Yes. both handing and passing are much easier to understand. Thank you, that's very kind of you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning of **slip** [given by Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/slip) is:

> **to go somewhere or put something somewhere quickly, often so that you are not noticed:**
>
> - ...
> - [ + two objects ] *If you slip the waiter some money/slip some money to the waiter he'll give you the best table.*

Slipping someone a tip means giving them a tip [discreetly](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/discreetly).

Answer (score 2):

"Slipping someone X" basically means "Giving someone X" or "Passing X to someone", perhaps with an implication that the action is discreet or subtle.