# Are "easily understood" and "easy to understand" interchangeable?

Tags: word-usage

This post is derived from another one ([the meaning of "slip a tip"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/240837/109190)).

Consider these sentences

> I'd like to picture myself as a wealthy patron casually **slipping** the doorman a substantial tip ...
>
> I'd like to picture myself as a wealthy patron casually **handing** the doorman a substantial tip

The latter is **easier to understand** for English learners. I can also say The latter is **more easily understood** for English learners.

So, are "[easily understood](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22easily%20understood%22)" and "[easy to understand](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%20%22easy%20to%20understand%22)" interchangeable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is yes. The differences are in the tense. Let's say T represents some time in the future.

**Easy to understand**: It will be easy to understand once it is read (at time T)
**Easily understood**: Once it is read (at time T), it *will have been* understood (just after T, making T in the past).

Subtle, but essentially the same.

Comment: Thank you. What does "at some future time T" mean? I guess T + 1 mean the day after a specific day.

Comment: Edited my answer to make it clearer (I hope!). The programmer in me likes to assign variables to things ;)

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Would you please make up a context. For instance, Michael teaches Alice C++, Alice think that is not easy to understand, then Michael teaches Alice Python, Alice think that is easy to understand.

Comment: I think when you're telling a story, you'd normally use "easy to understand", unless you're in character dialogue.